# Are ratios between spaces/generations in the Java Heap constant?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have read [this article](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) about virtual machine garbage collection  tuning to understand the java garbage collector better. Each space has a *Virtual* heap space area which it can grow into as the heap space needed gets closer to the max heap size. This can be seen in this picture:
[image: Java GC arrangement of generations]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/190244.gif))</sub>

You can set the ratio between *Young Generation* and *Old (Tenured) Generation* with the **NewRatio** parameter, and the ratio between *Eden Space* and *Survivor Space* with the **SurvivorRatio** parameter.

Recently [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413783/standard-allocation-ratio-for-java-heap) was asked about finding out the default ratios for the heap spaces. It says you should use the **PrintGCDetails** parameter and calculate the ratios manually.

My question is: Does the size of the different heap spaces increase by the same ratio, thus keeping the ratio set between them at startup constant during the whole runtime of the application? For example, if Young Generation and Old/Tenured Generation has a default NewRatio of 3, and the initial reserved heap space is 100MB for Young, and 300MB for Old. If more memory needs to be reserved for the Old Space, lets say 300MB more making it 600MB total. Does memory reserved for Young Space also double to 200MB keeping the ratio intact?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are referring to **GC Ergonomics** and the **Adaptive Size Policy**

- a feature of the Hotspost GC that automatically **adapts the sizes** of the generations **at runtime** based on the current allocation behavior of the running application.
- This feature is ON by default and controls/adapts the size of the generations at runtime.
- in fact, **some** of the **GC parameters** will be **ignored** if you do not disable Adaptive Size policy, eg. `-XX:SurvivorRatio=`.

You can **disable** the **Adaptive Size Policy**  by using the `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`. Once you disabled the AdaptiveSizePolicy, the GC will respect the initial size of the generations as specified by your startup parameters (e.g. `-Xms`, `-Xmx`, `-XX:MaxNewSize=`,`-XX:NewSize=`, `-XX:SurvivorRatio=`) and they will remain constant.

You can find more on Adaptive Size policy in [UseAdaptiveSizePolicy and other jvm opts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3634465/772000).

Comment: Good answer, explaining some concepts I did not know of beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

PermGen vs Young generation ratio is partially maintained by JVM, but to say if ratio is maintained, the answer is **No**.

JVM7 has become sufficiently advanced and complicated where we shouldn't predict the allocation of generations inside heap.

In every GC cycle that JVM runs, it also does metric analysis to learn of current applications in-memory storage behavior.
 - If more objects are surviving the multiple cycles of GC, then PermGen is reduced and some of the space is allocated to YoungGeneration. Basically `No. of objects` x `number of GC cycles they skip` plays a criteria in dynamically adjusting the generation ratio.

I hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand parts of your answer. 

"If more objects are surviving the multiple cycles of heap, then permgen is reduced and some of the space is allocated to YoungGeneration". 

If more objects are surviving, shouldn't it be OldGeneration that allocates more memory? Why bring permgen into the mix? And what if a NewRatio is specified in the startup parameters, is the ratio still not maintained?

Comment: That's a good question. 
" If more objects are surviving, shouldn't it be OldGeneration that allocates more memory?"
Yes it should be. What I mean is "PermGen is used ClassLoaders, and when JVM sees GC not able to clean out object (due to valid reasons) it tries to retrieve non-utilized memory from PermGen and allocate it for Object storage.
Wrt to your question, this allocation will go to OldGeneration or new generation, based on extrapolation algorithm used by JVM to determine near future allocation.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: I think I may have something wrong.  Putting this note here while I investigate, to keep from sending folks down the wrong path!**

Ales0x's answer is great if you are using Parallel Scavenge GC (`-XX:+UseParallelGC`), but Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC (`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`) does not support adaptive sizing.

With Concurrent Mark-Sweep, the new/young generation size is set based on the *initial* heap size (unless you specify `-XX:NewSize=`).  The new generation size will *not* change as the heap grows.